# Vertically centering a cross icon within a button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create multiple buttons and add cross icons to the button
like this

```css
.del {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height:1rem;
  width:1rem;
  margin-left:2rem;

}
.del:hover
{
  background-color: red;
}
.item
{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right:0.1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding:1rem 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="item"> item <span class="del">&times;</span></button>
<button class="item"> item <span class="del">&times;</span></button>
<button class="item"> item <span class="del">&times;</span></button>
```

But the 'x' visually seems to be not centered
Is there anyway I can get it to be within the center of the green circle?
or possibly modify it manually using only css and with the bare minimum code?

**EDIT**
I took a zoomed in picture of the dis-alignment of the 'x' so it could be easier to solve the problem and as you can see it is a bit lower
[image]

Comment: It looks vertically center to me... my eyesight isn't great though

Comment: It looks pretty okay to me as well here, but maybe you want to specify a `line-height`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using a font or text as the cross change your .del css display to inline-flex and then center it from there using justify-content and align-item

```css
.del {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height:1rem;
  width:1rem;
  margin-left:2rem;

}
.del:hover
{
  background-color: red;
}
.item
{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right:0.1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding:1rem 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="item"> item <span class="del">&times;</span></button>
<button class="item"> item <span class="del">&times;</span></button>
<button class="item"> item <span class="del">&times;</span></button>
```